# targeting and posting block quotes from posts

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

My Wordpress site's index.php has a div which posts the title, category, and featured image of the posts.

index.php HTML

```
<div>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
</div>
```

I have a single.php which brings in and puts the content of the post

single.php HTML

```
<div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

I want to bring a section of the_content of the post into my index.php (for example anything in the 'block quote' tag)

EX.

```
 <div>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    ... content from block quote    

    <h3><?php the_category(' '); ?></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I formatted your code a bit. Code blocks should be indented 4 spaces to render properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the content with [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content), then check if there's a blockquote and, if so, echo it:

```
// get the content
$content = get_the_content();
// check and retrieve blockquote
if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $content, $matches))
    // output blockquote
    echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: so I can put that as written in my html div tag?

Comment: yes, in your template file between the `H1` and `H3` tags, obviously inside a `<?php ... ?>` block

Comment: your code seemed to work great, and seems easiest to use. A secondary question though, what would I need to change to remove the 'block quote' section from the_content? I don't want it to show on the single.php if I have it showing on index.php

Comment: you need to [add a filter to the content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) and inside the filter function put `return preg_replace('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', '', $content);` to return a filtered content without blockquote

Comment: looks a bit complicated to a beginner developer like me, but you def put me on the right track, Thank you!

Comment: well maybe try first and if it's too complicated add another question and let me know it, I'll be glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse data from HTML tags using the DOM module. [This](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html) is an excellent guide to doing so.

You can also use REGEX (Somebody has shown this already so I removed the link I was gonna show)

Another option is to parse it yourself with explode etc. Like so:

```
//Get the content
$content = the_content();

//Explode to separate the first tags
$blockquotes = explode("<blockquote>", $content);

//Data array to use
$data = array();

//For each of these
foreach($blockquotes as $x){
    //Find the location of </blockquote>
    $end_loc = strpos($x, "</blockquote>");

    //Remove everything after by only taking everything before it
    $temp = substr($x, 0, $end_loc);

    //Add it to the array
    $data[] = $temp;
}

//Data now contains all of the data, do as you please with it
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: can I put that in my functions.php. or does that have to go in the html (if so exactly where?)